# Are system installed python applications or tools vulnerable to breaking if I uninstall a pip package as my username not sudo?

Tags: python, pip

As much as possible this is a cross OS platform question

After I have created and sourced a python virtual environment when I encounter pip install errors like

```
pip install tensorflow
...
Downloading protobuf-4.23.4-cp37-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (304 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 304.5/304.5 kB 3.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: protobuf
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
streamlit 1.12.0 requires protobuf<4,>=3.12, but you have protobuf 4.23.4 which is incompatible.
```

then outside of this python virt env I see I have streamlit installed as shown by issuing

```
pip list|grep streamlit
streamlit                     1.12.0
```

naturally I can remove this pip package using

```
pip uninstall  streamlit
```

I do not care about breaking anything I have installed dependent on `streamlit` or similar yet I want to avoid breaking other folks python applications/tools/etc

How tight is the referential integrity of system installed python applications regarding pip packages?

**UPDATE**

my guess is below should show dependencies on package in question

```
pkg=streamlit
grep ^Required-by <(pip show $pkg)
```

so if nothing is `Required-by` I should be free to uninstall offending package ... or no

I do not set env var PYTHONPATH

Comment: The question in the title is quite large, to the point where I am tempted to vote to close this as too unfocused, whereas the concrete problem you appear to be trying to solve in the actual question seems rather mundane and only vaguely related to the title. Perhaps you can [edit] to provide a less nebulous title?

Comment: @tripleee  updated title

Comment: For a general-purpose answer to the original, broad question, you might find https://edolstra.github.io/pubs/phd-thesis.pdf -- describing the academic basis behind what became https://nixos.org/, a reimagining of software distribution and packaging with hash-addressed links to reference-counted destinations -- interesting.

Comment: By contrast, I'm not sure there's enough information here to answer the narrow and specific question in a way that's guaranteed to be true, particularly across platforms, distributions, and software installation methods; details of your PYTHONPATH / `sys.path` and exactly how the software you're invoking is wrapped will matter intensely (but if the packaging for the specific software you're trying to run wasn't done with more than the minimal amount of care, the unwanted-but-accurate answer may be that you have no guarantees).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How tight is the referential integrity of system installed python applications regarding pip packages?

Not tight enough to provide concrete assurances. While the actions taken by pip for any given software installation action will attempt to honor the dependency chain for the software being installed at that time, later installation/uninstallation actions don't concern themselves with whether they break the dependency chains of other software not named in that specific operation.

There are toolchains that provide stronger guarantees -- I'm personally quite a fan of [Nix](https://nixos.org/), which when building a Python environment assembles it from hash-addressed entries in a read-only store, which can only be removed from that store when no references to them remain -- but you don't get that from pip alone *even within a single environment being managed by pip*, much less when there are multiple (system and user) environments overlayed into a single PYTHONPATH being managed independently of each other.